# How can sum all the totals for the products? Without Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in which the data is inserted dynamically and in which the total of each product is calculated by multiplying the price by the quantity and gives us its total. Well, what I want is to take the totals of all the totals of the products.

The table looks like this:

[image]

And the code is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/table.css">
</head>



<script>
  function fetchID() {
    let Id = window.location.search.split('=')[1];
    loadTable(Id);
  }

  function loadTable(id) {

    let totalOfTotals = 0;

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener("load", function(e) {

      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
          console.log(request.responseText); // datos de la factura
          // pasarla a objeto (JSON)

          var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

          var myObj = {
            code: data.code,
            date: data.date,
            lines: []

          };

          for (let i = 0; i < data.lines.length; ++i) {
            let tmp = data.lines[i];
            var line = {
              name: tmp.name,
              description: tmp.description,
              barcode: tmp.barcode,
              amount: tmp.amount,
              price: tmp.price
            };
            myObj.lines[i] = line;
          }

          document.getElementById("iddate").innerHTML = data.date;
          document.getElementById("idcode").innerHTML = data.code;

          console.log(myObj);

          let table = document.getElementById('matchData'),
            sumVal = 0;
          let line_count = myObj["lines"].length;
          let row = document.createElement("tr");

          for (let key in myObj) {

            /*if (key == "code" || key == "date") {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");

                cell.rowSpan = line_count;
                cell.textContent = myObj[key];
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }*/

            if (key == "lines") {

              let price = 0,
                amount = 0;
              for (let line_key in myObj[key][0]) {
                if (line_key == 'price') price = myObj[key][0][line_key];
                if (line_key == 'amount') amount = myObj[key][0][line_key];
                let cell = document.createElement("td");

                cell.textContent = myObj[key][0][line_key];
                row.appendChild(cell);
              }

              let cell = document.createElement("td");
              cell.textContent = price * amount;
              row.appendChild(cell);

              table.appendChild(row);

              for (let i = 1; i < line_count; i++) {
                let row = document.createElement("tr");
                let _price = 0,
                  _amount = 0;
                for (let line_key in myObj[key][i]) {
                  if (line_key == 'price') _price = myObj[key][i][line_key];
                  if (line_key == 'amount') _amount = myObj[key][i][line_key];
                  let cell = document.createElement("td");

                  cell.textContent = myObj[key][i][line_key];
                  row.appendChild(cell);
                }

                let _cell = document.createElement("td");
                _cell.textContent = _price * _amount;
                row.appendChild(_cell);
                table.appendChild(row);

              }
            }
          }

        } else {
          console.log("Error loading page\n");
        }
      }

    });
    request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8081/invoice/" +
      id);

    request.send();
  }
</script>


<body onload="fetchID()">

  <div class="date-div" id="iddate"></div>
  <div id="idcode"></div>

  <table id="demo">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Barcode</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th id="sum">Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Total</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody id="matchData"></tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Apart from this code I have another one for CSS and another HTML that is the one that directs you to the table but I don't know if you will need it, if you need it, tell me.

Do you have any idea how I could do it? I would also appreciate the explanation of how you have done it. If you need more information about something, ask for it and I will give it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you really changed something or ...?

Comment: There are two ways to do that. You can either maintain an array of items, where each item contains item details including amount and quantity, then you can just use .reduce method of array to get the total sum. Or you can perhaps maintain a data attribute for each row and get data value from DOM and calculate the total.

Comment: Could you show me how to do it? I'm pretty new to this and have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*.....what I want is to take the totals of all the totals of the products*

You can get the elements using `querySelectorAll()` and `nth-child` and sum them using `reduce()`.

**Demo:**

```js
var totalEl = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#demo tbody tr td:nth-child(6)')).map(el=> +el.textContent);
var sumTotal = totalEl.reduce((a,c) => a+c, 0);
document.querySelector('#demo tfoot tr td:last-child').textContent = sumTotal;
```

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="date-div" id="iddate"></div>
<div id="idcode"></div>

<table id="demo">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Barcode</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th id="sum">Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="matchData">
        <tr>
            <td>Teclado Logitech</td>
            <td>Teclado Logitech Gaming</td>
            <td>7634487</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Monitor HP 27f</td>
            <td>Monitor de 27″ HD</td>
            <td>2423467</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>1000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Raton Logitech</td>
            <td>Raton Logitech Gaming</td>
            <td>2345672</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>150</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Total</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because I can't get it to work.

Comment: @AlejandroFelipeGonzalez, there is some mismatch in the ordering if elements between the image and HTML you have provide. Just follow the logic in the answer and update yours, it should work:)

Comment: Now it works for me, I'm a little clumsy hahahaha, I already have it, thank you very much for the help, you just saved me.

Answer (score 2):

As you are already maintaining an array that contains all the items in it. You can simply use the reduce method to get the total value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/table.css">
  </head>


  <body onload="fetchID()">

    <div class="date-div" id="iddate"></div>
    <div id="idcode"></div>

    <table id="demo">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Barcode</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th id="sum">Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">Total</td>
          <td id="totalValue"></td> <!-- CHANGE MADE HERE, CREATED AN ID -->
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody id="matchData"></tbody>
    </table>

  </body>

<script>
  function fetchID() {
    let Id = window.location.search.split('=')[1];
    loadTable(Id);
  }

  function loadTable(id) {

    let totalOfTotals = 0;

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener("load", function(e) {

      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
          console.log(request.responseText); // datos de la factura
          // pasarla a objeto (JSON)

          var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

          var myObj = {
            code: data.code,
            date: data.date,
            lines: []

          };

          for (let i = 0; i < data.lines.length; ++i) {
            let tmp = data.lines[i];
            var line = {
              name: tmp.name,
              description: tmp.description,
              barcode: tmp.barcode,
              amount: tmp.amount,
              price: tmp.price
            };
            myObj.lines[i] = line;
          }

          document.getElementById("iddate").innerHTML = data.date;
          document.getElementById("idcode").innerHTML = data.code;

          console.log(myObj);

          let table = document.getElementById('matchData'),
            sumVal = 0;
          //Get the element, calculate the total value using reduce and set the value.
          const totalValueTd = document.getElementById('totalValue');
          totalValueTd.innerHTML = myObj["lines"].reduce((sum, item) => {
            return sum + (parseFloat(item.price, 10) * parseInt(item.amount, 10));
          }, 0);
          console.log(totalValueTd);
          let line_count = myObj["lines"].length;
          let row = document.createElement("tr");

          for (let key in myObj) {

            /*if (key == "code" || key == "date") {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");

                cell.rowSpan = line_count;
                cell.textContent = myObj[key];
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }*/

            if (key == "lines") {

              let price = 0,
                amount = 0;
              for (let line_key in myObj[key][0]) {
                if (line_key == 'price') price = myObj[key][0][line_key];
                if (line_key == 'amount') amount = myObj[key][0][line_key];
                let cell = document.createElement("td");

                cell.textContent = myObj[key][0][line_key];
                row.appendChild(cell);
              }

              let cell = document.createElement("td");
              cell.textContent = price * amount;
              row.appendChild(cell);

              table.appendChild(row);

              for (let i = 1; i < line_count; i++) {
                let row = document.createElement("tr");
                let _price = 0,
                  _amount = 0;
                for (let line_key in myObj[key][i]) {
                  if (line_key == 'price') _price = myObj[key][i][line_key];
                  if (line_key == 'amount') _amount = myObj[key][i][line_key];
                  let cell = document.createElement("td");

                  cell.textContent = myObj[key][i][line_key];
                  row.appendChild(cell);
                }

                let _cell = document.createElement("td");
                _cell.textContent = _price * _amount;
                row.appendChild(_cell);
                table.appendChild(row);

              }
            }
          }

        } else {
          console.log("Error loading page\n");
        }
      }

    });
    request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8081/invoice/" +
      id);

    request.send();
  }

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read the comments in the code (changed a bit of HTML and JS both)

Comment: Yes, I just tried it and it works perfectly, many thanks to you too.

Comment: Awesome! I am glad I could help